# Displaying Metadata from USGS Earthquake JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, metadata

-I am creating a live earthquake map website www.livehazards.com

-I am pulling. my data from UGSG website (GeoJson format). "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson"

The featurecollection/metadata for the features is 
{
type: "FeatureCollection",
metadata: {
generated: Long Integer,
url: String,
title: String,
api: String,
count: Integer
status: Integer
},

- I want to show/print the count interger in the side bar but have no idea what code to use to do this.

Anyone help, pls?

Comment: Count for what?

Comment: The count would show the number of features (Earthquakes) there have been within the last month

Comment: so currently feature size 5681 as per link. Right ?

Comment: Yes, it could be that high. How did you find the figure '5681'. My question is, what code should I use, so I can display that number (That number would be constantly changing). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here, I have prepare one example in which i have paste your sample 5 features object in JSON string (which is minified) and get the result.
You may apply the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
// JSON.parse(<JSON String>); // Json string is minified
var obj = JSON.parse('{"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1509005451000,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson","title":"USGS Magnitude 1.0+ Earthquakes, Past Month","status":200,"api":"1.5.8","count":5681},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":0.99,"place":"2km SE of The Geysers, California","time":1509005085910,"updated":1509005181998,"tz":-480,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72914101","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72914101.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":15,"net":"nc","code":"72914101","ids":",nc72914101,","sources":",nc,","types":",geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,","nst":7,"dmin":0.01315,"rms":0.01,"gap":159,"magType":"md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 1.0 - 2km SE of The Geysers, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.7351685,38.7636681,1.04]},"id":"nc72914101"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":1.01,"place":"14km ESE of Mammoth Lakes, California","time":1508996258570,"updated":1509000963664,"tz":-480,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72914056","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72914056.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":16,"net":"nc","code":"72914056","ids":",nc72914056,","sources":",nc,","types":",geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,","nst":8,"dmin":0.01545,"rms":0.03,"gap":96,"magType":"md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 1.0 - 14km ESE of Mammoth Lakes, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-118.8184967,37.6030006,4.35]},"id":"nc72914056"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":1.6,"place":"62km WNW of Beatty, Nevada","time":1508993349830,"updated":1508993549009,"tz":-480,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nn00610589","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nn00610589.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":39,"net":"nn","code":"00610589","ids":",nn00610589,","sources":",nn,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":31,"dmin":0.195,"rms":null,"gap":136.69,"magType":"ml","type":"earthquake","title":"M 1.6 - 62km WNW of Beatty, Nevada"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-117.4003,37.13,5.5]},"id":"nn00610589"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.03,"place":"1km ESE of Pahala, Hawaii","time":1508989731730,"updated":1508989927780,"tz":-600,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/hv61956446","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/hv61956446.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":63,"net":"hv","code":"61956446","ids":",hv61956446,","sources":",hv,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":42,"dmin":0.04174,"rms":0.19,"gap":105,"magType":"md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.0 - 1km ESE of Pahala, Hawaii"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-155.466507,19.1971664,33.47]},"id":"hv61956446"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":2.07,"place":"24km ENE of Soledad, California","time":1508987976180,"updated":1508999403619,"tz":-480,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72914021","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72914021.geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"automatic","tsunami":0,"sig":66,"net":"nc","code":"72914021","ids":",nc72914021,","sources":",nc,","types":",geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,","nst":18,"dmin":0.06662,"rms":0.05,"gap":130,"magType":"md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 2.1 - 24km ENE of Soledad, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-121.0631638,36.4811668,3.99]},"id":"nc72914021"}],"bbox":[-179.9476,-61.9084,-2.93,179.9778,71.4011,614.26]}');

alert(obj.features.length);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope, it's works. thanks :)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for doing that, It works but.....I need the number to update automatically (Instead of copying and pasting data sets every few hours). Also There must also be a way to print the count number directly from the website....without having to copy and paste 5000+ records from the ugsg website.

Comment: Always Welcome! What is the issue now? plz tell me :)

Comment: I will try explain 1) I don't know what the code would look like but maybe something like ......print (data.metadata.count)........I would like to display the count number automatically, which was '5681' in that string. 2) I also don't want it to be an alert but instead just display as a number on my sidebar. Thanks if you can help

Comment: Check another answer which is more dynamic. This ans is for small size of data. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson", function(json) 
          {
console.log(json);  
var newString = JSON.stringify(json, null, 0);
var obj = JSON.parse(newString);
document.getElementById("amount_of_earthquake").innerHTML = obj.features.length;
          });
</script>
<div id="amount_of_earthquake"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, it's works. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, thats amazing it worked. It came up as popup box (alert box) when I open the website. Do you have idea how to represent the result as just plain text, so I can put it in my sidebar?

Comment: Yes, it's simple! You can just use innerHtml to assign that value into html text. See https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-innerHTML

Comment: Hey thanks, I looked through that but still don't know how to assign the value. Would you be able to provide an example? Thanks

Comment: sure will.. which technology you are using right now? and yes you can approved this ans in case if it is helpful to you..

Comment: The data come up as an alert box when i open my site www.livehazards.com. I am using wordpress. I would like to convert that alert box and display that sentence in my Sidebar please

Comment: Sure You can! 
Provide me that code when you want to display this count.  @CharlesHarrison

Comment: <nav class="nav-sides">
  <a href="http://www.paypal.me/charrison223"><img src="http://livehazards.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/x-click-but21.gif" alt="" width="110" height="23" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2072"/></a> 
  Earthquake Statistics
**I would like the text to be displayed here. Saying there have been X amount of earthquake over the last month**
<script>
  </script>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Live Hazards small sidebar -->
  <script>

Comment: Replace **Earthquake Statistics I would like the text to be displayed here. Saying there have been X amount of earthquake over the last month ** 
With 
<div id="amount_of_earthquake"></div>

Comment: Hey, thanks. Ok I'vedone that. Do you know how to write the other part of the code which will link too< div id="amount_of_earthquake">

Comment: Sorry, Which Other part of the code ? did't understand what you want to say

Comment: ok ill try and explain. Thank you for making me an alert which comes up when i open my website www.livehazards.com See alert **$.getJSON("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson", function(json)
          {
console.log(json);  
var newString = JSON.stringify(json, null, 0);
var obj = JSON.parse(newString);("There have been  " + obj.features.length + "  Earthquakes in the last month");** My question is how do I transfer that javascript alert...into **text html** so I can put that in my sidebar, so i can put that sentence after **Earthquake statistics**

Comment: No no no no no!!
Check clearly! i have update answer and add one new line inside <script> tag which is "document.getElementById("amount_of_earthquake").innerHTML = obj.features.length;" that is as per your req.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, It worked. Sorry I am new too Stackoverflow so unfamiliar with this website. What is your email address/paypal? I have a few other small lines of code which I need doing, and would be willing to pay for those.

Comment: thanks I will whatsapp/email you soon. How do I approve the answer?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I've added your information so you can delete now your whats app/phone number